# Using SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry with Redis Session Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am using Spring Security and Spring Session (v1.3.1) in my application.

I would like to use [SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry.html) as my Session Registry and Redis as my Session repository.

The constructor for [SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry.html) is as follows:

```
SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository)
```

The Redis repository, [RedisOperationsSessionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.html) implements:

```
FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.RedisSession>
```

How, then, can I construct an instance of [SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry.html) given an instance of [RedisOperationsSessionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.html)?

Why is the constructor for [SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry.html) not:

```
SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession> sessionRepository)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry` should take `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession> sessionRepository` as constructor argument.

I've opened the PR to address the issue, you can track it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/700).

In the meanwhile you can use raw `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` in your configuration to configure `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry`. Here's an example:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(this.sessionRepository);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' in your configuration."